# Installing cert files and connecting to wifi network on Touchpad running CM9

Tags: wi-fi, certificates

Hi everyone I am trying to connect to my university wifi **eduroam** using the settings below:

http://www.lboro.ac.uk/it/wireless/technical.html

How can I achieve this? So far I've tried saving the crt file in the root folder of the SD card and installing it via *Security > Install from SD card* but I'm not sure how to take it from here.

Would appreciate any help on this matter.

Comment: What's your actual issue? Have you tried connecting to the network with the suggested settings after installing the certificate? There's also an IT helpline number on that page, have you tried contacting them?

Answer (score 1):

I connect with my Samsung GSII with CM9 to my eduroam network in the university of alicante. Here you have the link with instructions in english I followed on how to configure the wifi network:
http://si.ua.es/en/wifi/eduroam/peap/eduroam-installation-for-android.html

However, the issue is simple, you have to go to wifi settings, and add a new network manually, ssid will have to be "eduroam" and you will see that if you choose "802.1x EAP" security setting, more settings will appear where you can insert the info provided in the link of your question. Of course you will have to choose as CA certificate the one you installed already.

I hope this helps.
cheers

Comment: Nothing appears in the CA certificate box